# Why are my bitwise operations not working with `int`s in Java?

Tags: java

I just got the following compiler error:

```
./package/path/FrameScreenPosition.java:80: incompatible types
found   : int
required: boolean
    if (frame.getExtendedState() & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                                 ^
```

An 'extended state' is a bitwise mask of various different states such as maximized or iconified, and I'm trying to test whether the frame is maximized.  The following short example produces a similar error:

```
public class BitTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int a = 1;
    int c = 3;

    if (a & c) {
      System.out.println("This is right.");
    }
  }
}
```

Everything I've seen suggests that the bitwise operator `&` isn't restricted to boolean variables in Java, so why am I getting an error message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expression inside `if` *must* explicitly be a boolean (that is, `boolean` or `Boolean` -- see [JLS §14.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) for further details):

```
if ((a & c) != 0) {
```

Also note that the second set of parenthesis are required here since `!=` has a higher precedence than `&`.

Answer (score 3):

In Java `if(..)` clause must always evaluate to a `boolean` which is *its own type* unlike in, say, C.

So, `0`, `null` etc. are **not** converted to boolean `false` nor positive numbers to `true` and so on and so forth. You must include arithmetic comparison operator to specify what you really want.

Comment: Note that it can also evaluate to `Boolean`.

Comment: @arshajii Well yes, although `Boolean` is auto-unboxed to `boolean` in this context.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a & c)  wont work here;
```

`if(condition)` needs to have a boolean value.